# Show link on Razor LayoutPage from Content Picker on Homepage Umbraco

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm wondering how I can get a Node recursively inside my Layout.cshtml in umbraco.

I have a couple of properties on my Homepage DocumentType which are content pickers, and need to access the properties recursively on my masterpage.
How can i do this?

I know how to do this with a normal field by calling `Umbraco.Field("prop", recursive: true)`

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: So you want to loop every selected items in the content picker, and then select properties from every node in the loop?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty similar really:

```
Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("myProperty", true)
```

or

```
@CurrentPage.GetPropertyValue("myProperty", true)
```

This is lesser known but also works

```
@CurrentPage._myProperty
```

I assume you know how to get the node from the Content picker?

```
var nodeId = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("testRecursive", true);
var node = Umbraco.TypedContent(nodeId);
```